# What is meaning of defined keyword

Tags: perl

Please give me the meaning of this code.

```
defined( $params->{tco_cvv} )  and $pay_method->{cvv}   = $params->{tco_cvv};
```

I can't understand the meaning of this please reply me

Comment: Googling for "perl defined" gives you the exact answer and it's the first hit. It's easier to do that to ask the question here on SO.

Comment: Actually I am a java programmer and try to understand Perl. So i googled this and couldn't to find the answer.

Comment: I googled for "Perl defined" and the *first* hit was http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html. I can't understand how you managed to miss that. "Let me Google that for you" links are forbidden on SO but they're very appropriate for questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

- 0 if EXPR contains undef
- 1 if EXPR contains a valid value or reference

Comment: It's `""` (the empty string) if EXPR contains `undef`.

Answer (score 2):

This code is equivalent to

```
if ( defined $params->{tco_cvv} )  {
    $pay_method->{cvv} = $params->{tco_cvv};
}
```

I.e., if the `tco_cvv` parameter is defined, its value is set to `$pay_method->{cvv}`.